# How do I append a bit string in text block of a Windows Store app?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, binaryfiles, windows, huffman-code

The code that I m using is shown below

```
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    tb2.Text = ((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
}
```

How do I modify above code to get the whole required string? I am working on Huffman compression of text files. And after this step i need to create and store tht bit string in a binary file.Please tell me the futher procedure. Thnx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, you are replacing the content in tb2.Text at each iteration. By getting the whole required string, do you mean that you want to concatenate the string? If so, this will work:

```
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    tb2.Text += ((bit ? 1 : 0) + "");
}
```

Comment: thnx fr ur help. It worked. :) .Please help me out in proceeding further. My question is in above comments.

Comment: Glad I could help. That's a pretty different problem not related to your original problem. I suggest you open a new question where you ask for help regarding your second problem.

Answer (score 1):

At the very least you need to concatenate the values

```
foreach (bool bit in encoded)
{
    tb2.Text += ((bit ? 1 : 0 ) + "");
}
```

Or you can just do this

```
tb2.Text = string.Join("", encoded.Select(b => b ? "1" : "0"));
```

Or even this

```
tb2.Text = new string(encoded.Select(b => b ? '1' : '0').ToArray());
```

Comment: Thank u so much fr ur help. Can u Please help me out how do I proceed further? I need to store this bit string I got in a binary file. How do I create it? I am developing an windows store app for text files compression.

Comment: @ShahinAhmed You should create a new question for any additional help that you need.